# Call div only once in ngFor when first ngIf occurs inside the loop

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have this code right here:

```
  <div *ngFor="let condition of interior_conditions; let i = index" class="condition-item-2">
    <div class="condition-title">{{condition.name}}</div>
    <div class="condition-content">
      <div class="row">
        <hr class="my-hr">
        <div class="col-12">
          <span *ngFor="let zone of zones">
            <span *ngFor="let poor_condition of zone.poor_conditions">
              <span *ngIf="poor_condition._id==condition._id" class="danger_zones">
          <span>
            Danger Zones:
          </span>
                {{zone.name}}
              </span>
            </span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The thing is this:

- I have a lot of conditions and zones in my db
- The zones have poor and good conditions, they may have only good conditions, not necessarily both
- I iterate through the conditions
- Later, i iterate through the poor conditions
- So, if a zone have poor conditions i want to print the zones name and have the 'title' danger zones only ONCE

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please add more description? Do you mean you have a lot of "danger zoons" and you just one to show one of them?

Comment: Is condition._id defined?

Comment: only the first iteration of ngFor? give us more details to be able to help you

Comment: I updated my question, thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think the only way that can be done is through a Service, where a function will have input the condition and return the zones that have this condition poor

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can't or don't want to move the span outside the loop, you can add an `ngIf` based on the index:

```
<span *ngIf="i === 0"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this would not work though since the condition may occur later and not on the first iteration. I updated my question with more info!

Answer (score 0):

you should move the span with title Danger Zones.

```
  <div *ngFor="let condition of interior_conditions; let i = index" class="condition-item-2">
    <div class="condition-title">{{condition.name}}</div>
    <div class="condition-content">
      <div class="row">
        <hr class="my-hr">
        <div class="col-12">
          <span *ngFor="let zone of zones">
          <span>
            Danger Zones:
          </span>
            <span *ngFor="let poor_condition of zone.poor_conditions">
              <span *ngIf="poor_condition._id==condition._id" class="danger_zones">
                {{zone.name}}
              </span>
            </span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: In this way the Danger Zones will be print even if the zone has no poor condition, which is something that i do not want..